# How to make thousand separator for a price in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, preg-replace, price

I wrote this code (on woocommerce/single-product/price.php) a few months ago but I lost it, I was lucky to recover the code but in its first phase. Before the result gave me a thousand separation, I think it was because of the "preg_replace" function.

```
<?php echo '$' . round((preg_replace('/^[\.]/', '', $product->get_price()) *1.04)); ?>
```

The result that shows me is similar to: $311896. The format I'm looking for: $311.896

I will show you how it works. I add a tax to a payment gateway (that's why I used formula x1.04). It is shown in this way:
[image]
The original price if it is formatted correctly, but my code is not. It is a headache.

Comment: [number_format](http://php.net/number_format) or [money_format](http://php.net/money_format).

Comment: what do you get in  $product->get_price()?

Comment: @Alberto the price of the woocommerce product!

Comment: Ops, sorry, I was talking to @CaptainObvious.

Comment: http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_price_thousand_separator/  Will this help you

Answer (score 5):

This is not needed in woocommerce, if you have set the thousand separator in Woocommerce general settings:

[image]

You just have to use the dedicated price formatting function [**`wc_price()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_price.html#505-563) that will do everything for you even the currency symbol:

```
<?php echo wc_price( $product->get_price() * 1.04 ); ?>
```

It is recommended to use it with [**`wc_get_price_to_display()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_price_to_display.html#989-1007) function this way:

```
<?php echo wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_price() * 1.04 ) ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$a='299900';
echo '$' . number_format($a*1.04);
```

the output is: $311,896

if you want to display "." instead of the "," you can do that via the function extra parameters, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php